# I want to display the all true/false questions in same page using quiz module. Is it possible?

Tags: 7

I have installed drupal 7 quiz module in my project.I want to display the all true/false questions in same page. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "Same Page" ?

Comment: Quiz module display the one question per page. I want to display the all true/false questions in per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  [Quiz Progress](https://drupal.org/project/quiz_progress) module .. It offers nice User Experience to track status of questions and navigation..

Project page says

> Quiz 6.x has the limitation of displaying only one question at a time.
> This makes it hard to navigate from one question to other especially
> when you have a skipped question in the beginning and you have your
> current question at the closure of quiz.
>
> The "Quiz Progress" module tries to overcome this problem, it provides
> a block that prints the list questions in the quiz referenced by title
> or number (with tooltip) depends on the widget configured in module
> settings, highlighting their status skipped, answered or unanswered as
> a link.

Here is the final output using above module which lists all questions...

[image]

If you are looking for Solution from Quiz Module itself take a look at this [issue](https://drupal.org/node/503228) in Quiz Module.. Seems like #106 works in above issue..

Answer (score 0):

Add content to  "Quiz Page" content type. For example "All true/false questions" --> Go to "Manage QUestions"--> Add the newly created "Quiz Page" question-->Simply drag and drop "True/False QUestions underneath the newly added question "QUiz Page"